# how to keep the rows that have replicates

Tags: r

I have been trying to find a way to keep the rows that have at least 3 strings replicates but it seems like I cannt figure it out

the data looks like this

```
df<-structure(list(First = c("TAGAA1", "TAGAA2", "GYI1", "GYI2", 
"BBB", "TTT", "GGG10", "NNN", "GGG4A", "GGG4B"), FD1 = c("TAGAA1", 
"TAGAA2", "GYI1", "GYI2", "", "", "GGG10", "", "GGG4A", "GGG4B"
), FD2 = c("TAGAA1", "TAGAA2", "GYI1", "GYI2", "", "", "GGG10", 
"", "GGG4A", "GGG4B"), FD3 = c("TAGAA1", "TAGAA2", "GYI1", "GYI2", 
"", "", "GGG10", "", "", ""), FD4 = c(NA, NA, "GYI1", "GYI2", 
"", "", "GGG10", "", "", ""), FD5 = c("TAGAA1", NA, "GYI1", "GYI2", 
"", "", "GGG10", "", "", ""), FD5.1 = c("TAGAA1", NA, "GYI1", 
"GYI2", "", "", "GGG10", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

for example, the following does not give me

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df)) >= 3, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing data is represented as `NA` AND empty cell `""` in your data, so `!is.na()` alone is not going to work.

```r
df[rowSums(df != "" & !is.na(df)) >= 3,]

# A tibble: 7 × 7
  First  FD1    FD2    FD3      FD4     FD5      FD5.1   
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   
1 TAGAA1 TAGAA1 TAGAA1 "TAGAA1"  NA     "TAGAA1" "TAGAA1"
2 TAGAA2 TAGAA2 TAGAA2 "TAGAA2"  NA      NA       NA     
3 GYI1   GYI1   GYI1   "GYI1"   "GYI1"  "GYI1"   "GYI1"  
4 GYI2   GYI2   GYI2   "GYI2"   "GYI2"  "GYI2"   "GYI2"  
5 GGG10  GGG10  GGG10  "GGG10"  "GGG10" "GGG10"  "GGG10" 
6 GGG4A  GGG4A  GGG4A  ""       ""      ""       ""      
7 GGG4B  GGG4B  GGG4B  ""       ""      ""       ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
subset(df, Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, nzchar)) >=3)
```

-output

```
 First    FD1    FD2    FD3   FD4    FD5  FD5.1
1  TAGAA1 TAGAA1 TAGAA1 TAGAA1  <NA> TAGAA1 TAGAA1
2  TAGAA2 TAGAA2 TAGAA2 TAGAA2  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3    GYI1   GYI1   GYI1   GYI1  GYI1   GYI1   GYI1
4    GYI2   GYI2   GYI2   GYI2  GYI2   GYI2   GYI2
7   GGG10  GGG10  GGG10  GGG10 GGG10  GGG10  GGG10
9   GGG4A  GGG4A  GGG4A                           
10  GGG4B  GGG4B  GGG4B
```